# how to do ng-repeat with hashmap

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hashmap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display my data on ionic/angular with hashmap using this [hashmap](https://github.com/flesler/hashmap), my data is very simple:

set methods:

```
tables.set(1, "string one");
tables.set(2, "number one");


    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='(key, value) in tables'>
      <span>Key: {{key}}, value: {{value}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

the issue is that I can't get it working on ng-repeat to show all the key, value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying found the solution

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='(key, value) in tables._data'>
      <span>Key: {{key}}, value: {{value[1]}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```